# android shows blank white screen when 64bit .so file loading... no issue with 32bit so file

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, .so

W/System.err: Native code library failed to load.

```
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64','armeabi'
    }
```

when i put 64bit .so file simulator showing just a white blank screen.but there is no prob with 32bit .so file

Comment: There's not enough information here for anyone to be able to say why your library failed to load. What is the full error log? Which specific 64-bit architecture are you testing on? Is there actually a corresponding library for that architecture in your APK? How was it built?

Comment: Are you copying 64bit.so file in  ```x86_64``` and ```arm64-v8a``` directory as well? Are you sure that your recompiled .so files is 64 bit compliance? show your ```jniLibs``` directories for batter understanding

Comment: arm64-v8a and x86_64 contains 64bit .so files.Previously it was workink with 32 bit .so files. now we need to change to support 64 bit also. so they generated 64bit .so files . wen i rendering blank white screen only

Comment: is it any problem with .so file which they created?

Comment: I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
 W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
 E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
 I/art: Debugger is no longer active
 I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content

Comment: private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
V/[SAIFE Connect]: [SaifeSessionModel : initialize] : Initialize model, initialized -> false
 W/System.err: Native code library failed to load. 
 W/System.err: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.saife.connect-2/lib/x86/libgnustl_shared.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40
 I/art: System.exit called, status: 1
 I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 1, cleanup skipped.

Comment: `e_machine = 40` means ARM. So it seems like you're trying to load an ARM library on an x86 system.

Comment: thanks michael almost found the issue

Comment: showing error "Failed to initialize crypto engine"  from .so file. There they used open ssl for cryptography. but it is working with 32 bit apk , not with 64bit

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Failed to initialize crypto engine
        at com.saife.lib.bindings.saife_adapter_libJNI.SaifeProxy_AddEntropy(Native Method)
        at com.saife.lib.bindings.SaifeProxy.AddEntropy(SaifeProxy.java:303)
        at com.saife.impl.SaifeImpl.AddEntropy(SaifeImpl.java:496)
        at com.saife.connect.controllers.authentication.saife.SaifeAuthServiceImpl.addEntropy(SaifeAuthServiceImpl.java:621)